# Binomial probability for sporting event where the order of the first 3 outcomes does not matter

Tags: probability

There is a sporting event where team A has $1/3$ chance of winning and team B has a $2/3$ chance of winning. In order to win a team needs to be the first to win 4 matches. There are no ties.

The question: What is the probability that team A will win?

My thoughts:

It will take no more than $7$ matches for team A or B to win.

Neither team will win within $3$ matches, so the order for the first $3$ matches does not matter.

The possible scores where A wins are 
$(4 - 0)$
$(4 - 1)$
$(4 - 2)$
$(4 - 3)$

So I need to find the binomial probability for each possibility and sum them.
However, the order of the first 3 matches does not affect the outcome, so they should not be included in the $nCr$ part.

That's where I'm stuck as to how I need to write out $nCr$ for each possibility whilst taking into account that the order of the first $3$ matches does not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We describe two different approaches. Assume independence (this is not reasonable, in many games there is a home rink/field advantage).

Way $1$: **Imagine** that whatever happens, the teams  keep on playing until $7$ games have been played played. Then Team A wins the real Stanley Cup finals if and only if in the modified series A wins $4$ *or more* games of the $7$ games. The probability A wins $4$ games in the modified series is $\binom{7}{4}(1/3)^4(2/3)^3$. The probability it wins $5$ is $\binom{7}{5}(1/3)^5(2/3)^2$. And so on. Add up.

Way $2$: We look at the real series, and calculate the probability the series lasts $4$ games and A wins it, the probability the series lasts $5$ games and A wins it, and so on up to $7$.

The probability A wins in $4$ is $(1/3)^4$.

For winning in $5$ games, A must win $3$ of the first $4$, and then win the fifth. The probability of winning $3$ of the first $4$ games is $\binom{4}{3}(1/3)^3(2/3)^1$. Multiply by $1/3$ to find the probability of winning in $5$ games.

To win in $6$ games, A must win $3$ of the first $5$, and then win. The probability is $\binom{5}{3}(1/3)^3(2/3)^2(1/3)$.

Now write down the probability of winning in $7$ games, and add up.

Comment: I calculated both and got the answer $379$$/$$2187$ for both. Way 2 I understand completely, but am still having issues understanding exactly why way 1 works.

Comment: Also, the answer I am given for this question uses $\binom{3 + n}{n}(1/3)^3(2/3)^n$ . It gives the same answer... but I don't understand the reasoning behind using $3$$+$$n$ $nCr$ $n$.

Comment: I would have to see the full formula given, including the interval of summation. It would be correct to say $\sum_0^3 \binom{n+3}{n}(1/3)^4 (2/3)^n$. Here $n$ counts the number of games Team B wins, so $n+4$ is the number of games played before the series ends. That's basically the formula given explicitly by drhab, and it is the summation described in my Way 2.  For note that $\binom{n+3}{n}=\binom{n+3}{3}$. The author focused on wins by B, and we focused on total number of games.  But the formula described in your comment above has a $(1/3)^3$, which is not right.

Comment: Now for my Way 1.  I imagined changing the rules, and even if a team wins the series early, say in the fifth game, they keep playing the full $7$ games. Then Team A might win more than $4$ games. Team A wins the series under the usual rules if and only if it wins $4$ or more of the $7$$ games under the altered rules. Now we can use straight binomial distribution.

Comment: P("A wins 3, B wins n") = $\binom{3+n}{n}(1/3)^3(2/3)^n$ is what the author's answer says. I realise that it made much less sense without a further explanation of it. Afterwards it is multiplied by $1$$/$$3$ in the same way as in way 2 here. So it makes sense now! I found it helpful to think about way 1 so that I focus on team B. 7 games are the maximum and B is not allowed to win more than 3. It is the same thing, but somehow it helped me make more sense of this interpretation of the question.

Comment: The "afterwards it is multiplied by $1/3$"  is what changes that $(1/3)^3$ to $(1/3)^4$.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ wins after exactly $k\in\left\{ 4,5,6,7\right\} $ matches
then $A$ must win match $k$ and must win $3$ of the $k-1$ matches
that precede match $k$.

The probability that $A$ wins the $k$-th match is $\frac13$.

The probability that $A$ wins $3$ of the $k-1$ matches
that precede match $k$ is $\binom{k-1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{3}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{k-4}$.

So if $p_{k}$ denotes the probability that $A$ wins after exactly
$k\in\left\{ 4,5,6,7\right\} $ matches then: $$p_{k}=\binom{k-1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{4}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{k-4}$$

The probability that $A$ wins is: $$\sum_{k=4}^{7}p_{k}$$